# traits api creating new trait and trait changed behavior

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I often find myself in this situation:

```
class A:...

B=class
    a=Instance(A,())
    @on_trait_change('a')##I would really like to be able to do this
    def do_something(...)
```

I think that this currently triggers if you were to reset the entirety of the class. e.g. b=B(). b.a=A() should trigger it. But I would like to control when my custom class signals that it has been 'changed'. Per haps one might like A to signal 'changed' if merely a member of A is changed e.g. b.a.x+=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `A` and `B` derive from `HasTraits`, then changing your decorator to `@on_trait_change('a.+')` will do what you want. If you change the signature of your `do_something` to two or more arguments, you'll even be able to detect which attributes of `a` changed. (See http://traits.readthedocs.org/en/latest/traits_user_manual/notification.html#notification-handler-signatures.)

Comment: Yeah I guess I should settle for that... I doesn't literally do what I want, though

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to manually manage the events yourself, which traits certainly allows you to do.

Comment: @aestrivex Hi, I know this is coming literally 6 years later, but could you elaborate on how to do that? I've been trying to figure out how to manually trigger events from a custom class using the traits API for some time now and haven't managed to find a way.